# Button and Alert?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and a text.

If a user enters "Hi" in the textbox and then click on the button he should get a javascript alert "HELLO!" how can i make that ?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: What code have you tried that is not working for you?  Please post it here.

Comment: You can do that using JavaScript. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I had a button too. But I eated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following code in script:-

```
function hello()
{
  if(document.getElementById("txtboxid").value == "HI")
   alert("HELLO");
}
```

Call above function on the click event of the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sayHello()
        {
            theTextbox = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
            alert("Hello!");
            alert(theTextbox.value);

            if(theTextbox.value == "Hi")
            {
                alert("You did enter Hi in the textbox!");
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="myTextbox" />

    <button onclick="sayHello()" text="Click me!" />
</body>
```